# Set a default character-encoding to UTF-8 in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, character-encoding

How can I set the default Mozilla Firefox character-encoding to UTF-8, so if the HTML page lacks the *meta* tag to set *charset*, the character encoding is interpreted as UTF-8?

Comment: I'd be interested in that as well. Western encoding is probably the stupidest default encoding I could imagine in this internet era. If I'm not mistaken there actually *used* to be a setting for setting the default encoding in earlier versions of Firefox, so it seems the developers at Mozilla must have gotten rid of it…

Comment: @balu: What is "Western encoding"? [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's been a while but I *think* I was referring to [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which used to be the default encoding for `text/*` MIME types. Or *maybe* I was referring to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which became the default for HTML 5 and often got mislabeled as ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 9):

In Firefox, open a new tab, go to `about:config` and press the confirm button.

Search for the key "intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file" and double-click to set its value to `true`.

This solution works with offline HTML files that don't contain the *charset* meta tag.

Comment: from what i understand, this only works for offline files, not actual files from the web. see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308469/30227

Comment: Can you elaborate on the offline part? Something with HTTP headers? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49686975/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

There is no browser-side setting for this. If there was, people authoring content would make content that looks right for them but would be broken for other readers.

If the HTML file is loaded from a `file:` URL and the content is UTF-8, Firefox autodetects it at the cost of breaking incremental rendering, but incremental rendering isn't important for `file:` URLs, since the content is assumed to be finite and available quickly.

For online content, the setting is whatever configuration makes your server send `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

[Longer explanation](https://hsivonen.fi/utf-8-detection/)